# K8S/EKS - rebalancing memory ratio

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

why does the scheduler in 1.20 does not try to rebalance the memory distribution in the following statistics, the usage is taken by x3 replicas setup with homogenous amount of memory taken per replca service (approx 200~ Mi diff), why doesn't the scheduler move away loads automatically, there are 3 minimum nodes guaranteed and affinity for replicas on same host or same AZ when there are 3 AZs I don't understand why this is happening.

```
/snap/bin/kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.12", GitCommit:"4bf2e32bb2b9fdeea19ff7cdc1fb51fb295ec407", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-10-29T02:43:48Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20+", GitVersion:"v1.20.7-eks-d88609", GitCommit:"d886092805d5cc3a47ed5cf0c43de38ce442dfcb", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-07-31T00:29:12Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
kubectl top nodes
NAME                                         CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%
some-ip.eu-west-2.compute.internal    112m         2%     2238Mi          33%
some-ip.eu-west-2.compute.internal   859m         5%     14881Mi         52%
some-ip.eu-west-2.compute.internal    887m         5%     18485Mi         65%
some-ip.eu-west-2.compute.internal   1900m        11%    27727Mi         97%
some-ip.eu-west-2.compute.internal   368m         9%     3975Mi          60%
some-ip.eu-west-2.compute.internal   196m         5%     3602Mi          53%
some-ip.eu-west-2.compute.internal   1450m        9%     27539Mi         97% (edited)
```

Comment: Can you please describe what is wrong currently - you have problems with your cluster or you just want to rebalance your pods across nodes to diverse the load of the system? Sorry, but it is not clear from your post. Also, did you make any steps and what steps to resolve your problem?

Comment: Hi, both, I want K8s to rebalance the loads without me needing to restart pods manually to achieve it. I have spring boot services unlocked on memory that get OOM bc of the 97% limit state of some of the nodes.

Comment: Sorry for delay. Is there any progress in solving this problem? You were wroting about your Spring Boot pods as they OOMKilled. Why do you think this is due to "the 97% limit state of some of the nodes" and not the problem with the pod itself? You can also use [Limit Ranges](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/limit-range/) to restrict resource consumption.